# Access UITabBarController to assign action via Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Without storyboards, I can simply assign the `UITabBarController.delegate = self` (in `AppDelegate`, for example). This lets me handle what happens when a `UITabBarButton` on the `UITabBar` is pressed.

However, I'm now using storyboards, where my `UIViewController` is contained in a `UINavigationController`, which is contained in a `UITabBarController`.

What's the best way to access this parent `UITabBarController` in code? I'd like to do this so I can assign a delegate to it. When the user presses a button in the `UITabBar`, I want to take an action in my contained `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.navigationController?.tabBarController`